# Upgraded Laravel 5.6 project has old Bootstrap

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I'm new in programming world and I've some problem.

I have a project created in Laravel 5.5. I upgraded it to 5.6 by edit `composer.json` and execute composer update.

I observed some problems with Bootstrap features, so I tried to check my bootstrap version, and in header of `public > css > app.css` I saw  * Bootstrap v3.3.7

How to upgrade it?

My tests:

1)

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.0.0
composer update
```

It doesn't help.

2) New project has the newest Bootstrap version.

Comment: Check the migration docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: I've checked it and there is some syntax changes. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you have to update the package.json for new bootstrap version, not composer.json. composer.json is for php packages and package.json is for npm modules.

Comment: were you able to fix your issue? might want to share how it was fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.1.1 --save-dev
```

It'll override Bootstrap 3 and install the latest version of Bootstrap v4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You're right.

Install the newest version of bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

but it looks like add another bootstrap near last version:

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0"
}
```

I don't know how to replace bootstrap 3.*

Comment: You have committed  "--save-dev" argument. Add it and  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0", "popper.js": "^1.13.0" will be moved under "devDependencies".